# vim: manipulate dictionary popup for autocompletion

Tags: vim, autocomplete, dictionary

I would like to tweak vim for using cdo ([Climate Data Operators](https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo/wiki/Cdo#Documentation)) efficiently. Because I need to use cdo in (bash) scripts, I would like to add an autocomplete matching (implemented!) with small description (still searching!).

I setup the environment and it works on a basic level. For now, I am wondering whether it's possible to manipulate the output of the pop-up menu on the right side of the matching dictionary keywords.

I got a simple keyword matching so far, see picture below:

Using the following setup:

My .vimrc:
`set completeopt=longest,menuone`

Includes different dictionaries, mainly cdo.dic: ~/.vim/ftdetect/cdo.vim:

`au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sh set dictionary+=~/.vim/dictionary/cdo.dic
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sh set dictionary+=~/.vim/dictionary/hamocc.dic
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sh set dictionary+=~/.vim/dictionary/mpiom.dic`

My dictionary file ~/.vim/dictionary/cdo.dic: with is matched against

`abs -abs \`
`adisit -adisit \`
...around 700 more....

**Goal**: What I would love to get as output is a small description that is displayed at the right, instead of the filepath of the dictionary file. So preferably a short explanation of the operator (which might be also stored in the dictionary file after the operator?), eg. for illustrative purpose

`selcode         : Select parameters by code number {selcode,code ifile ofile}`

read from a dictionary line:

`selcode -selcode {Select parameters by code number [selcode,code ifile ofile]}\`

So basically, I quick lookup tool for operator names and short description without large programming, plugins with other external tools. So it's an 'Is it possible and how?' question...

I tried so far the vim documentation, and googling about vim, dictionary, complete, completeopt, pmenu, ...

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot influence the context information of dictionary completion (unless you directly change Vim's source code).

However, Vim provides the ability to implement custom completions. You'll find all relevant information and an example at `:help complete-functions`. With that, you have full control over the context (named `menu`, cp. `:help complete-items`).

You can stick with dictionary files as your source; you'd have to read in the file (e.g. via `readfile()`) and slightly parse it (`matchlist()`), or you directly define your dictionary items as a Vim List, in the Vim script implementing your custom completion.

Comment: Thanks, Ingo. I choose the second option with a VimList. However now I am stuck reading in data from a file. `let l:data = [
        \ ["selvar","selvar,varname","Select a variable"],
        \ ["sellonlatbox", "sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2","Select a longitude/latitude box"]
    \ ] ` but I dont get in loaded from a different file, eg. .vim/dictionary/cdo.dic with the same content as this hardcoded static entries. So basically I dont understand the `readfile()` command and how to use it

Comment: so now it only works with `for m in l:data   if l:m[0] =~ '^' . a:base` but not with something like `for m in readfile("cdo_new.dic")`

Comment: now I managed to read in files via readline(), but I face the problem that all files are read in as vimL list items, so `'item1','item2'` but I want to get `item1,item2` because my items are lists like `["selvar","selvar,varname","description"]` Is there any way to manipulate readfile in that way?

Comment: I used the split function to read in items separately and then glued created a nested list out of those. Not pretty, I will see soon whether this also runs smooth with 1500 entries.

Comment: works fine - done

Comment: thats how I solved it: https://github.com/aaronspring/cdo_lazy_vim

Answer (score 0):

Finding this question led me to write a plugin:

https://github.com/jsit/vim-customcpt

It's built from the plugin that aaron.spring built in response to Ingo Karkat's accepted answer, but accepts any arbitrary json file as an autocomplete "dictionary".